# .load jquery function not working when using specific div

Tags: jquery, load

This line does not work

```
$('#bookcontainer').load( startSlide );
```

while this line does

```
$(window).load( startSlide );
```

`#bookcontainer` is a `div` containing four images.

Here's my whole code:

```
// JavaScript Document
$('#bookcontainer').load( startSlide );

var slide;

$('#slider').hover( 
function() {
        $('.arrow').show();
}, 
function() {
        $('.arrow').hide();
});

function startSlide() {
    $('.book').show();
    slide = setInterval(slideR, 5000);   
}


function slideR() {
    $('.book').first().css('left', '960px').appendTo('#bookcontainer').animate(
    {
        "left": "-=960px"
    }, {
        duration: 1000,
        easing: 'easeOutCubic'
    });

}


function slideL() {
    $('.book').last().animate(
    { "left":"+=960px" }, {
        duration: 1000,
        easing: 'easeOutCubic',
        complete: function() {
        $(this).prependTo('#bookcontainer').css('left', '0px');   
        }
    });

}


function right() {
    clearInterval(slide);
    slideR();
    startSlide();
};


function left() {
    clearInterval(slide);
    slideL();
    startSlide();
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The load event can only be handled on **elements that are associated with a url.** From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/):

> The load event is sent to an element
>   when it and all sub-elements have been
>   completely loaded. This event can be
>   sent to any element associated with a
>   URL: images, scripts, frames, iframes,
>   and the window object.

If you're waiting on all of your images to load, you could apply the event handler to those images individually.

Also: `$(window).load(...)` will not be fired until all elements on the page are fully loaded (including graphics), so it's not necessary to bind the event to a `div` to make sure child elements have loaded.

If you're making an AJAX request and attempting to detect when content has been loaded into that `div`, you should make `startSlide` the success callback to your AJAX request.

Comment: how do I call a function once a div containing images (hence all the images) is loaded?

Comment: @user643440: If you use `$(window).load(...)`, all images inside that `div` (and all other `div`s) will have loaded.

Comment: I gave the last image in the div an ID and called `$('#lastbook').load(startSlide);` Start slide will not go until all the images are loaded, pretty sure.

Comment: cannot use `$(window).load(...)` because a different script is using it

Comment: @user643440: You can bind multiple event handlers to `$(window).load(...)` and it won't cause issues.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `$('#bookcontainer').load('url', startSlide );` have a look at http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score -1):

The div element does not trigger a `load` event.

Comment: load is not an event but jQuery's shorthand method to load contents through Ajax call

Comment: @jatanp: Not true: `load` *is* an event and its only triggered on certain elements, see my answer for more information.