# jQuery height() returns 0 on a visible div - why?

Tags: jquery, css

I have a container (thetext1) with a set height of 360px.  "thetext1" contains two divs - one on the left and one floated to the right - into both of which content is delivered through an ajax call.

There will be times when the content in one or other of these divs exceeds 360px and so I want to increase the height of thetext1 accordingly.

My test code

```
newhgt = $('#thetext1').find('div.rhs').css("background", "pink").height();
```

returns 0 - (my selector is correct as the targeted div is perfectly pink!).

Why is this?  I know - from answers to previous posts on this site - that the solution is to add overflow: hidden thetext1, but I would like to understand why my attempt to get the height of the rhs and lhs div is failing.

Comment: If the elements are floated you may need to contain them by setting overflow: hidden on the bounding box or clearing floats in the next element

Comment: Are the contained elements both floated (left and right) ? You probably have to clear the floating on the container so it actually contains its children.

Comment: You say content is delivered through an ajax call. Are you reading the height after the ajax call?

Comment: 'Working' example of the code that is giving you trouble is a big help for people that are answering so that they can inspect what is actually going wrong and identify the problem instead of asking you about every single detail. ( http://jsfiddle.net )

Answer (score 37):

Make sure the code is inside the $(window).load [not $(document).ready ]

```
$(window).load(function () {
    newhgt = $('#thetext1').find('div.rhs').css("background", "pink").height();
});
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on why we would use the window.load instead of document.ready in this or similar cases? Thanks!

Comment: To be honest, I'm not 100% sure. It just worked though. My guess is that document.ready is just that. The elements of the documents are downloaded and the DOM is 'ready' whereas window.load means the window has loaded and the dimensions have been calculated.

Comment: @Gazzer .height was returning 0 for me in webkit browsers like Opera and Chrome. Using $(window).load(function () { }); worked for me. Thanks

Comment: For me the height was 0 in webkit browsers at document.ready time and was correct at window.load time. Possibly because of floated elements that might still be adjusted by the rendering engine. Setting overflow: hidden for the container of the floated elements made it so that the height was correct at document.ready time.

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem, and I noticed one thing, the div needs to be visible when you call .height();

But, **even if the div is visible, the parents of this div needs to be visible.**
So you must **garantee that parents div are visible (display != none)**

writing a `$('#div').parent().show();` will make a parent visible, you may need anothers `parent().show();`

Comment: I thought this might be the issue. But in my case I have a bounding box with two images inside. One is small, within the box, it gets that height. But the other goes past the boundary (boundary having overflow hidden). 0 height returned on that one. Bounding box is display none while fetching details. So it makes it hard to believe this would be it. All heights are properly grabbed afterwards doing other functions.

Answer (score 9):

You can still use $(document).ready as long as you check to see if the element is loaded first.  I chose to go with

```
 $("_element name/id_").load(function() {
      $(this).height();
 });
```

I originally found the solution here: 
http://www.fortwaynewebdevelopment.com/jquery-width-or-height-always-returns-0-fix/

And chose to use the answer in the first response.

Comment: Note that the load event can only be handled on elements that are associated with a url - it won't work for divs for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5253821/load-jquery-function-not-working-when-using-specific-div. Also for later jquery the syntax had changed from .load(handler) to .on('load', handler)

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem like this:

```
setInterval(function(){
  alert($("#element").height());
}, 1000);
```

It works for me.

Comment: setInterval or setTimeout you mean?

Answer (score 0):

```
newhgt = $('#thetext1').find('div.rhs').css("background", "pink")[0].getBoundingClientRect().height;
```