# bootstrap 3 responsive table with two fixed column

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

i'm using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19737306/bootstrap-3-responsive-table-with-fixed-first-column) answer to fixed my first columns inside bootstrap table.

i want to make the first TWO columns fixed, what do i need to change on the code?

Answer (score 0):

Change this line `$fixedColumn.find('th:not(:first-child),td:not(:first-child)').remove();`

to your desired column with `:nth-child() Selector`

```
 $fixedColumn.find('th:not(:first-child),td:not(:first-child)').remove();`
`$fixedColumn.find('th:not(:nth-child(2)),td:not(:nth-child(2))').remove();`
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line $fixedColumn.find('th:not(:first-child),td:not(:first-child)').remove();

to your desired column with :nth-child() Selector

```
$fixedColumn.find('th:not(:nth-child(-n+2)),td:not(:nth-child(-n+2))').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the line

```
$fixedColumn.find('th:not(:first-child),td:not(:first-child)').remove();
```

With

```
$fixedColumn.find('th:not(:first-child,:nth-child(2)),td:not(:first-child,:nth-child(2)').remove();
```

Notice that you can keep adding up columns as you please

Answer (score 0):

You can set a class for pin n columns as you prefer:

```
var $table = $('.table-pinned');
var $fixedColumn = $table.clone().insertBefore($table).addClass('fixed-column');

$fixedColumn.find('th,td').not('.pinned').remove();

$fixedColumn.find('tr').each(function (i, elem) {
  $(this).height($table.find('tr:eq(' + i + ')').height());
});
```

Here [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lughino/4XG7T/1349/)