# Bootstrap 3 responsive table with first fixed column

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsiveness

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19737306/bootstrap-3-responsive-table-with-fixed-first-column?lq=1) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30449054/fix-first-column-of-a-bootstrap-table?lq=1) post to lock width of first column. Table is responsive and I want to achieve fixed width of first column when I resize the table. I tried [Guruprasad's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30450495) post, but it doesn't work.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0t6t21rg/)

**html**

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Number</th>
                <th>Table heading</th>
                <th>Table heading</th>
                <th>Table heading</th>
                <th>Table heading</th>
                <th>Table heading</th>
                <th>Table heading</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>First</td>
                <td>Table cell</td>
                <td>Table cell</td>
                <td>Table cell</td>
                <td>Table cell</td>
                <td>Table cell</td>
                <td>Table cell</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Second</td>
                <td>Table cell</td>
                <td>Table cell</td>
                <td>Table cell</td>
                <td>Table cell</td>
                <td>Table cell</td>
                <td>Table cell</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Third</td>
                <td>Table cell</td>
                <td>Table cell</td>
                <td>Table cell</td>
                <td>Table cell</td>
                <td>Table cell</td>
                <td>Table cell</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.table>thead:first-child>tr:first-child>th:first-child
{
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    height:100%;
}
.table> tbody > tr > td:first-child
{
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    height:100%;

}
.table>thead:first-child>tr:first-child>th:nth-child(2)
{
    padding-left:40px;
}
.table> tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2)
{
    padding-left:50px !important;

}
```

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://jsfiddle.net/4XG7T/3/)

Comment: please check this one..http://jsfiddle.net/0t6t21rg/7/ let me know if its not work for you...

Comment: @Nameismy yes i tried, but it doesn't work. The first column is too narrow, if you fill cells with longer text, you can see that first column hasn't fixed width when you resize the table.

Comment: @Leothelion thank you, it works :) You can post it as answer and i can mark it as solution :)

Comment: th:first-child, tr td:first-child {
    width: 20px !important;
}

Comment: ok posting..give me one sec..ty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have edited your fiddle and did some changes like i removed `display:inline-block` and position and added fix width for that column so it will stay there.

```
.table>thead:first-child>tr:first-child>th:first-child
{
    height:auto;
    width:100px; /*change according to your need*/
}
```

For more details please check this  [link](http://jsfiddle.net/0t6t21rg/7/) .

Answer (score 0):

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed table-responsive">
</table>
```

Comment: Where is first fixed col ?