# How to freeze first or first n columns of bootstrap table?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to make table whose first column is freezed when scrolling horizontally as well as vertically.
I have gone through this stackoverflow question

[bootstrap 3 responsive table with fixed first column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19737306/bootstrap-3-responsive-table-with-fixed-first-column)

It is having answere too but it is having some bugs. I want to give fix height to the table. When I give the table height fix then first column is overflown as shown in this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/nt7fd965/144/

JS:

```
var $table = $('.table');
var $fixedColumn = $table.clone().insertBefore($table).addClass('fixed-column');

$fixedColumn.find('th:not(:first-child),td:not(:first-child)').remove();

$fixedColumn.find('tr').each(function (i, elem) {
    $(this).height($table.find('tr:eq(' + i + ')').height());
});
```

CSS:

```
.table-responsive>.fixed-column {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
}
@media(min-width:768px) {
    .table-responsive>.fixed-column {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="table-responsive" style="height:300px">
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Table heading</th>
            <th>Table heading</th>
            <th>Table heading</th>
            <th>Table heading</th>
            <th>Table heading</th>
            <th>Table heading</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
            <td>Table cell</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the solution
[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/T9Bhm/7/)

```css
table {
width: 100%;
}

thead, tbody, tr, td, th { display: block; }

tr:after {
content: ' ';
display: block;
visibility: hidden;
clear: both;
}

thead th {
height: 30px;

/*text-align: left;*/
}

tbody {
height: 120px;
overflow-y: auto;
}

thead {
/* fallback */
}


tbody td, thead th {
width: 19.2%;
float: left;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Make</th>
        <th>Model</th>
        <th>Color</th>
        <th>Year</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
            <tr>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Ford</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Escort</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">Blue</td>
        <td class="filterable-cell">2000</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Comment: First column is not fixed.. :(

Comment: i think you should check demo link first

Comment: the header is fixed, not the first column