# How to make <td> height of fixed first column same as rest of the row?

Tags: html, html-table

I have a table which can be scrolled horizontally. I have fixed the first column, so that it stays in place while rest of the columns are scrolled. It is working fine, except first `<td>` elements do not have same height as rest of the row.

HTML:

```
<div>
<table>
        <tr><th class="headcol">1</th><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPAS<br />DFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td></tr>
        <tr><th class="headcol">2</th><td class="long">QWERTYUIO<br />PASDFGHJKL<br />ZXCVBNM</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td></tr>
        <tr><th class="headcol">3</th><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td></tr>
        <tr><th class="headcol">4</th><td class="long">QWERTYUI<br />OPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td></tr>
        <tr><th class="headcol">5</th><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td></tr>
        <tr><th class="headcol">6</th><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td><td class="long">QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM</td></tr>
</table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
table {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid grey;
}

td, th {
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-top-width: 0px;
}

div {
  width: 500px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  margin-left: 5em;
  overflow-y: visible;
  padding: 0;
}

.headcol {
  position: absolute;
  width: 5em;
  left: 0;
  top: auto;
  border-top-width: 1px;
  /*only relevant for first row*/
  margin-top: -1px;
  /*compensate for top border*/
}

.headcol:before {
  content: 'Row ';
}

.long {
  background: yellow;
  letter-spacing: 1em;
}
```

Here is jsfiddle: [jsfiddle.net/cgg97cmr/](https://jsfiddle.net/cgg97cmr/)

If you check the jsfiddle, you will see that `<td>` elements in first column do not adjust their height according to rest of the row. I want them to act like normal `<td>` belonging to their respective rows.

Comment: Correct me if I don't understand the question right. You want all the collums the same heigt, with the current `<br>`? If so you can do 2 things: set a default height for al the collums to be the same heigt(CSS). Or you can use jquery to read the heigt and then adjust your collum to that height

Comment: I see, i implemented a function with jquery but it can only be used with a `static` or `relative` postition. Hold on while I look for something else

Comment: see this.https://stackoverflow.com/a/19739775/7951293

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking for.